# How to make VAT field dependent from Company field for shipping address during checkout process?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.2

I would like to have a dependency between VAT and Company fields for shipping address during checkout. Whenever VAT is filed, Company should be set as required field and the other way.

Should I use some kind of mixin for such problem? Something like in the documentation - https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_field.html#mixin

Answer (score 1):

I achieved a similar result by extending the input element.

In my case I added a check box to hide/show company fields via afterProcess() plugin on \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor.

```
    $addressFieldset['custom_checkbox'] = [
        'component' => 'Vendor_CustomerCustomAttributes/js/ui/form/element/single-checkbox',
        'config' => [
            'customScope' => $dataScope,
            'template' => 'ui/form/field',
            'prefer' => 'toogle'
        ],
        'dataScope' => $dataScope . '.custom_checkbox',
        'deps' => $deps,
        'label' => __('Are you a Company?'),
        'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
        'visible' => true,
        'initialValue' => false,
        'sortOrder' => 155,
        'valueMap' => [
            'true' => true,
            'false' => false
        ]
    ];
```

below the component js

```
define([
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/single-checkbox',
    'mage/translate'
], function (AbstractField, $t) {
    'use strict';

    return AbstractField.extend({
        defaults: {
            streetLabels: [$t('Company / Section / Unit'), $t('Post Sector Type'), $t('Post Sector')],
            modules: {
                country_id: '${ $.parentName }.country_id',
                company: '${ $.parentName }.company',
                vat_id: '${ $.parentName }.vat_id',
                cod_fisc: '${ $.parentName }.cod_fisc',
                sdi: '${ $.parentName }.sdi',
                pec: '${ $.parentName }.pec'
            }
        },
        
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();
            this.updateFieldVisibility();
        },
        
        updateFieldVisibility: function () {
            this.company().visible(this.value());
            this.vat_id().visible(this.value());
            if(this.country_id().value() == 'IT'){
                this.cod_fisc().visible(false);
                this.sdi().visible(this.value());
                this.pec().visible(this.value());
            } else {
                this.cod_fisc().visible(false);
                this.sdi().visible(false);
                this.pec().visible(false);
            }
        },
        
        onCheckedChanged: function () {
            this._super();
            this.updateFieldVisibility();
        }
    });
});
```

You can use this approach to modify the component of the VAT and Company fields and achieve the desired behavior.

Comment: Thx for help.I'll give it a go. Do you maybe know how to make field required in the js component?

Comment: have a look to a required fiel and check classe and attribute of elements